# Can the critical P-value returned by the Benjamini-Krieger-Yekutieli (BKY) procedure be greater than the false discovery rate?

Tags: statistical-significance, inference, p-value, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

If I use the Benjamini-Krieger-Yekutieli (BKY) procedure for an FDR correction, is it possible for the critical P-value returned to be greater than the desired false discovery rate? I just tried applying the BKY procedure using [this Matlab code](https://github.com/dmgroppe/Mass_Univariate_ERP_Toolbox/blob/master/fdr_bky.m) from the mass univariate ERP toobox, I set the desired FDR to 0.05 and it gave me a critical P-value of 0.055 ... so that's more generous than if I hadn't corrected at all ... Can the output be correct?